# contact-channel-address is auto prefix with +1 when using Twillio Studio - make outgoing call

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

Using Twilio Studio to make a non US out going call. The trigger is from RESTapi. The Twilio widget auto-prefix the outgoing number with +1.

I tried to use Twilio Studio to make a non US out going call. The trigger is invoked from RESTapi. In the URL, I supplied contact number. The Twilio widget auto-prefix the outgoing number with +1. Hence the call was not successful.

```sh
curl -X POST "https://studio.twilio.com/v1/Flows/FXXXXXXX/Executions" -d "To=+6598XXXXXX"
```

response:

```
{"status": "active", "date_updated": null, "contact_channel_address": "+16598XXXXXX", "ac..
```

I send only +6598.. the populated data in `contact_channel_address` contains additional 1

Should be the number that I sends.

Comment: This is bizarre and since your code appears correct I recommend you contact [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and notify them of the Flow SID and any execution or call SIDs that were affected so that they can track down what is going on.

Comment: I've raised a ticket with Twilio support. Pending for their fixes.